# Special Characters JSON iOS SQLite

Tags: ios, json, sqlite

I have one question. 
I'm getting information from JSON and he returns me invalid character. 
JSON give me this: "27/"" when I need this: 27". I understand this is a encode for special characters but when I use the value on NSString to make an Insert in a SQLite table, I can't use 27/" cause the insert format is this: INSERT INTO FORMATOS (ID, NOMBRE) VALUES ("17", "27"").

What method I need to Insert information correctly in the SQLlite?

```
for (int i = 0; i<idFormato.count; i++) {
            NSString *idStr = [idFormato objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *nameStr = [nameFormato objectAtIndex:i];

            insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO FORMATOS (ID, NOMBRE) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\")", idStr, nameStr];

            //Char constant with the query encoded un UTF
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            //Execute query
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(dieneDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

            //Check if Statment is dne correctly
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
                NSLog(@"Guardado Formatos correctamente");
            }
```

The JSON:

```
[

    {"ID_FORMATO_INT":"17","NOMBRE_FORMATO_STR":"2,5\"","ID_USUARIO_ALTA_INT":"3","FECHA_ALTA_FORMATO_DAT":"2014-09-18 07:17:55","ID_USUARIO_MOD_INT":null,"FECHA_MOD_FORMATO_DAT":null},{"ID_FORMATO_INT":"18","NOMBRE_FORMATO_STR":"4\"","ID_USUARIO_ALTA_INT":"3","FECHA_ALTA_FORMATO_DAT":"2014-09-18 07:18:20","ID_USUARIO_MOD_INT":null,"FECHA_MOD_FORMATO_DAT":null},{"ID_FORMATO_INT":"19","NOMBRE_FORMATO_STR":"4,7\"","ID_USUARIO_ALTA_INT":"3","FECHA_ALTA_FORMATO_DAT":"2014-09-18 07:20:07","ID_USUARIO_MOD_INT":null,"FECHA_MOD_FORMATO_DAT":null},{"ID_FORMATO_INT":"20","NOMBRE_FORMATO_STR":"5,5\"","ID_USUARIO_ALTA_INT":"3","FECHA_ALTA_FORMATO_DAT":"2014-09-18 07:20:15","ID_USUARIO_MOD_INT":null,"FECHA_MOD_FORMATO_DAT":null},{"ID_FORMATO_INT":"21","NOMBRE_FORMATO_STR":"9,7\"","ID_USUARIO_ALTA_INT":"3","FECHA_ALTA_FORMATO_DAT":"2014-09-18 07:20:42","ID_USUARIO_MOD_INT":null,"FECHA_MOD_FORMATO_DAT":null},{"ID_FORMATO_INT":"22","NOMBRE_FORMATO_STR":"7,9\"","ID_USUARIO_ALTA_INT":"3","FECHA_ALTA_FORMATO_DAT":"2014-09-18 07:21:04","ID_USUARIO_MOD_INT":null,"FECHA_MOD_FORMATO_DAT":null},{"ID_FORMATO_INT":"23","NOMBRE_FORMATO_STR":"11\"","ID_USUARIO_ALTA_INT":"3","FECHA_ALTA_FORMATO_DAT":"2014-09-18 07:22:40","ID_USUARIO_MOD_INT":null,"FECHA_MOD_FORMATO_DAT":null},{"ID_FORMATO_INT":"24","NOMBRE_FORMATO_STR":"13\"","ID_USUARIO_ALTA_INT":"3","FECHA_ALTA_FORMATO_DAT":"2014-09-18 07:22:44","ID_USUARIO_MOD_INT":null,"FECHA_MOD_FORMATO_DAT":null},{"ID_FORMATO_INT":"25","NOMBRE_FORMATO_STR":"15\"","ID_USUARIO_ALTA_INT":"3","FECHA_ALTA_FORMATO_DAT":"2014-09-18 07:22:49","ID_USUARIO_MOD_INT":null,"FECHA_MOD_FORMATO_DAT":null},{"ID_FORMATO_INT":"26","NOMBRE_FORMATO_STR":"21,5\"","ID_USUARIO_ALTA_INT":"3","FECHA_ALTA_FORMATO_DAT":"2014-09-18 07:23:11","ID_USUARIO_MOD_INT":null,"FECHA_MOD_FORMATO_DAT":null},{"ID_FORMATO_INT":"27","NOMBRE_FORMATO_STR":"27\"","ID_USUARIO_ALTA_INT":"3","FECHA_ALTA_FORMATO_DAT":"2014-09-18 07:23:14","ID_USUARIO_MOD_INT":null,"FECHA_MOD_FORMATO_DAT":null}

]
```

Comment: And show us how you're creating the INSERT statement.

Comment: The JSON you posted does not contain `27"` or anything resembling that.  However, you would avoid a lot of problems if you used "prepared statements".

Comment: BTW, when you get past the immediate problem, you might consider doing a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before your `for` loop and a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` after the `for` loop. Without that, it will commit these individual `INSERT` statements individually, which can be quite slow (esp if you have a lot of data to insert). By using transactions, you will commit all of these updates at once, which can be more efficient. Clearly, fix the immediate issue first, but when you get that behind you, you might want to consider using transactions for better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're building your SQL with`stringWithFormat`. That is a practice that is susceptible to this sort of problem. Instead, use `?` placeholders in your SQL and then use `sqlite3_bind_text` to bind values to the `?` placeholders. See the [`sqlite3_bind_text()` help](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) for more information.

For example, you might:

```
const char *insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO FORMATOS (ID, NOMBRE) VALUES (?, ?)";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dieneDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {  // prepare SQL
    NSLog(@"prepare error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(dieneDB));
} else {
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, idStr, -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {            // bind 1
        NSLog(@"bind idStr error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(dieneDB));
    } else if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, nameStr, -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {   // bind 2
        NSLog(@"bind nameStr error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(dieneDB));
    } else if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {                            // perform SQL
        NSLog(@"step error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(dieneDB));
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Guardado Formatos correctamente");
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

I just typed this in, so please forgive any typos, but hopefully it illustrates the idea.

Note, I also (a) check all of these return codes; (b) log the error if any; and (c) finalize the statement when done.

Comment: It's worth noting that [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) simplifies this, doing all of this in a single statement. I know it's a more dramatic shift than you might want to contemplate right now, but if doing a lot of SQLite programming, FMDB make life much easier.