# How to get data from Sqlite database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have create sqlite db Table as below

```
NSString * sqlStmt =@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SONGS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, SONGNAME TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,ALBUMNAME TEXT ,ARTIST TEXT ,SIZE FLOAT ,IMAGE BLOB)";
```

when i am trying to get data from this table getting nothing

```
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"SELECT ARTIST ,IMAGE FROM SONGS WHERE SONGNAME=kannulada"];
```

but iam getting data when iam trying to get data by id.

```
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"SELECT ARTIST ,IMAGE FROM SONGS WHERE id=1"];
```

when i debugging  it not excuting prepare loop

```
-(NSMutableArray*)retrieveDataArrayWHICHISequql
{
  [dataArray removeAllObjects];
 sqlite3_stmt  *statement;

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_SQliteDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    const char * selectQuery =[sqlQuery UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_SQliteDB, selectQuery, -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)== SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString * addressStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

            NSString * phNumStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

            //  NSString * nameStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];

            NSMutableDictionary * dataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dataDict setObject:addressStr forKey:@"getaddress"];
            [dataDict setObject:phNumStr forKey:@"getphone"];
            // [dataDict setObject:nameStr forKey:@"getname"];

            [dataArray addObject:dataDict];

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_SQliteDB);

    }

}
return dataArray;
```

Comment: are you used any case sensitive related to this `kannulada`

Comment: i am using exact the same as song name                                                NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO SONGS (SONGNAME ,ALBUMNAME ,ARTIST ,SIZE ,IMAGE) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",self.currentSongTitleName,self.currentSongAlbum,self.currentSongArtistName,display,self.imageDataFromMusic];

Comment: use `'kannulada'`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thankyou bro its working

Comment: welcome my sis/bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I HAVE string in sqlite db  kick (2009) but i am getting kick(2009) namespaces are skipping but i need exact same in sqlite db?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152505/discussion-between-savarala-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString 

    stringWithFormat:
                    @"SELECT ARTIST ,IMAGE FROM SONGS WHERE SONGNAME='kannulada'"]

;
```

kannulada is string , so you must use single quote

Comment: I HAVE string in sqlite db  kick (2009) but i am getting kick(2009) namespaces are skipping but i need exact same in sqlite db?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that if you have an error in `sqlite3_prepare_v2` (it didn't return `SQLITE_OK`). So, if that happens, you should look at what [`sqlite3_errmsg`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) returned, and it will tell you precisely why it failed. If you don't look at the meaningful error message that SQLite returns, you're flying blind.

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_SQliteDB, selectQuery, -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
{
    ...
} else {
    NSLog(@"SQL Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_SQliteDB));
}
```

Regarding why it's failing, it's because you have to either quote the string literal, `'kannulada'`, or, better, use a SQL placeholder, `?`, and then use `sqlite3_bind_text`.

Comment: will u elobarate ur ans?

Comment: iam new to ios   [ this one sqlite3_bind_text.]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386276/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920119/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/21507483/1271826

Comment: I HAVE string in sqlite db  kick (2009) but i am getting kick(2009) namespaces are skipping but i need exact same in sqlite db?